# Alternative to "yeah" as an acknowledgement

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to stop myself using the word "yeah" in certain contexts where it seems too informal. But I'm not sure how to replace it. Consider this example:

```
> "I need to cancel our meeting on Monday"
> "Yeah, it gets busy this time of year"
```

"Yeah" is generally considered a more casual "yes", but here it serves as an acknowledgment. "Yes, it gets busy..." would sound weird because there was no question that was asked to say yes to. Is there an alternative word that can replace "yeah"?

I suppose I could rewrite the sentence to: "It really gets busy this time of year", but the difficulty with this is that you need to think of a way to rephrase each sentence that uses "yeah" rather than there being a general rule.

Comment: I would say *yeah* is not an acknowledgement, but an affirmation in the above, agreeing that the meeting needs to be canceled. *Yes, it gets busy this time of year* as would be *right …*, *true …*, or flat-out *I agree …*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "**I understand**. It gets busy this time of year."

Answer (score 1):

Consider the expression "you bet."

> *[**You bet**](http://www.funnyjunk.com/funny_pictures/1128327/Canada/5), it gets hot here in the summer.*

Answer (score 1):

- **Sure**, *it gets busy this time of  year;* may be an informal  alternative, or
- **I see,** *it gets busy this time of  year*;  less informal.

Comment: "Sure" works really well

Answer (score -1):

Affirmative
Yup
Yes
Most definitely
Absolutely

Comment: pick a word, cite its definition and support it in her sentence or your own. sentence